# How to check if a file is opened by another process in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writing a log reader program in Node.js and need to check if a log file is used by another process (the process that is writing the log). The program is running on Windows. I've tried the following, but it seems that the log file is not locked when it is open and being written to, and therefore fs.openSync will always succeed.

```
function checkOpened(filePath){
var fd=0;
try{
    fd=fs.openSync(filePath, 'r+');
}catch(err){//cannot lock the file
    console.log(err.code);
    if(err.code === "EBUSY"){
        return true
    }
    return false;
}
try{
    fs.statSync(fileP)
    fs.closeSync(fd);
    fs.unlinkSync(filePath);
}catch(err){
    //Doesn't really care
}
  return false;
}
```

How can I check if a file is opened by another process in Node.js then?

EDIT: Apparently it is possible to use `fs.rename` to check if a file is being used (it will fail to do so if the file is used by another process). I will settle for this for now.

Comment: What is the use case?

Comment: I seriously doubt you can do that. But I could definitely be wrong.

Comment: Which OS are you doing this on?  This is not a directly supported feature of node.js so one would have to research OS-specific solutions.

Comment: I am working on Windows. Apparently it is possible to use `fs.rename` to check if a file is being used (it will fail to do so if the file is used by another process). I will settle for this for now.